# How to solve issue with JavaMail -> javax.mail.MessagingException: 220

Tags: java, exchange-server, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to generate a connection with the Exchange Server of my company, and retrieve some email from it. I'm using a code that I took from the following page, http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html , and I'm being able to get connected, but I'm getting the following error:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.search.*;
import javax.activation.*;


public class FetchMailUsage {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP's POP3 SERVER HERE!!!
    String host = "pop.yourisp.net";
    // SUBSTITUTE YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO ACCESS E-MAIL HERE!!!
    String user = "your_username";
    String password = "your_password";
    // SUBSTITUTE YOUR SUBJECT SUBSTRING TO SEARCH HERE!!!
    String subjectSubstringToSearch = "Test E-Mail through Java";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    // To see what is going on behind the scene
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.port", "25");

    // Get a session.  Use a blank Properties object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    try {

        // Get a Store object
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(host, user, password);

        // Get "INBOX"
        Folder fldr = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        fldr.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        int count = fldr.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println(count  + " total messages");

        // Message numebers start at 1
        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                            // Get  a message by its sequence number
            Message m = fldr.getMessage(i);

            // Get some headers
            Date date = m.getSentDate();
            Address [] from = m.getFrom();
            String subj = m.getSubject();
            String mimeType = m.getContentType();
            System.out.println(date + "\t" + from[0] + "\t" +
                                subj + "\t" + mimeType);
        }

        // Search for e-mails by some subject substring
        String pattern = subjectSubstringToSearch;
        SubjectTerm st = new SubjectTerm(pattern);
        // Get some message references
        Message [] found = fldr.search(st);

        System.out.println(found.length +
                            " messages matched Subject pattern \"" +
                            pattern + "\"");

        for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
            Message m = found[i];
            // Get some headers
            Date date = m.getSentDate();
            Address [] from = m.getFrom();
            String subj = m.getSubject();
            String mimeType = m.getContentType();
            System.out.println(date + "\t" + from[0] + "\t" +
                                subj + "\t" + mimeType);

            Object o = m.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("**This is a String Message**");
                System.out.println((String)o);
            }
            else if (o instanceof Multipart) {
                System.out.print("**This is a Multipart Message.  ");
                Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;
                int count3 = mp.getCount();
                System.out.println("It has " + count3 +
                    " BodyParts in it**");
                for (int j = 0; j < count3; j++) {
                    // Part are numbered starting at 0
                    BodyPart b = mp.getBodyPart(j);
                    String mimeType2 = b.getContentType();
                    System.out.println( "BodyPart " + (j + 1) +
                                        " is of MimeType " + mimeType);

                    Object o2 = b.getContent();
                    if (o2 instanceof String) {
                        System.out.println("**This is a String BodyPart**");
                        System.out.println((String)o2);
                    }
                    else if (o2 instanceof Multipart) {
                        System.out.print(
                            "**This BodyPart is a nested Multipart.  ");
                        Multipart mp2 = (Multipart)o2;
                        int count2 = mp2.getCount();
                        System.out.println("It has " + count2 +
                            "further BodyParts in it**");
                    }
                    else if (o2 instanceof InputStream) {
                        System.out.println(
                            "**This is an InputStream BodyPart**");
                    }
                } //End of for
            }
            else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
                System.out.println("**This is an InputStream message**");
                InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
                // Assumes character content (not binary images)
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(c);
                }
            }

            // Uncomment to set "delete" flag on the message
            //m.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED,true);

        } //End of for

        // "true" actually deletes flagged messages from folder
        fldr.close(true);
        store.close();

    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) {
        // Prints all nested (chained) exceptions as well
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();

       }
     }

} //End of class
```

The trace of the error is the following:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsy stems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/me/My%20Documents/QA/Automation/javamail-1.4.4/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "167.107.252.184", port 25, isSSL false
220 SERVER Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Tue, 13 Sep 2011 15:38:38 -0500 
javax.mail.MessagingException: 220 SERVER Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Tue, 13 Sep 2011 15:38:38 -0500 ;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: 220 SERVER Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Tue, 13 Sep 2011 15:38:38 -0500 
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:663)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.test.ewacs.test.pageobjects.utilities.FetchMailUsage.main(FetchMailUsage.java:38)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: 220 SERVER Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Tue, 13 Sep 2011 15:38:38 -0500 
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.processGreeting(IMAPProtocol.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:120)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:110)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:632)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I have not dabbled into email for a while but I think your issue is you are connecting to the SMTP port (25) but the protocol you are using is IMAP.

Take a look at:
http://www.hascode.com/2010/04/snippet-simple-one-minute-imap-client/

Comment: Thanks, I made that change due that the only port that is responding is 25, and it seems that Javamail doesn't support SMTP protocol.

Comment: No that is not true. Javamail does support SMTP. Talk to your mail server admin and figure out what port is the IMAP server running on. Also ensure that there are no firewall rules that prevent you from connecting you to your mail server.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I reviewed with server admins and they are using  MAPI or RPC over HTTPS, so I'm trying to figure it out how to handle that, I didn't see nothing yet Java based usefull for that...

Comment: If you are familiar with the protocol you could write the library (shudder!!) or use an exchange connector such as this one. http://www.moonrug.com/ BTW, would it be too much of an ask for your admins to open up the email server to use IMAP or POP? Just wondering.

Comment: Yes, is almost impossible, this is a huge company, and they don't wanna take risks, it seems that the first option will be the proper choice in this case, cause I'm not sure if there are exchange connector open sources... I'll look into it, at least before to start inventing the wheel again... thanks a lot for all your comments

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/ is an open source library. Hopefully it works for you. Also, if you found the answer to your problem to be correct, please go ahead and accept it so that others facing a similar issue can know if this worked for you or not.